# Python Requests - add text at the beginning of query string

Tags: python, python-requests

When sending data through python-requests a GET request, I have a need to specifically add something at the beginning of the query string. I have tried passing the data in through dicts and json strings with no luck.

The request as it appears when produced by requests:

```
/apply/.../explain?%7B%22......
```

The request as it appears when produced by their interactive API documentation (Swagger):

```
/apply/.../explain?record=%7B%22....
```

Where the key-value pairs of my data follow the excerpt above.

Ultimately, I think the missing piece is the **record=** that gets produced by their documentation. It is the only piece that is different from what is produced by Requests.

At the moment I've got it set up something like this:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username,password)
s.verify = certificate_path

# with data below being a dictionary of the values I need to pass.
r = s.get(url,data=data)
```

I am trying to include an image of the documentation below, but don't yet have enough reputation to do so:

[apply/model/explain documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Z5x.png)

Comment: From docs `r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)` watch the `params` instead of `data` var,  see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Params allows you to pass in a dict of key value pairs. I don't need a key-value pair, just that simple string, unless I am misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: `record` is your key and `%7B%22` your value ;)

Comment: I added some clarity above. %7B%22 was not my actual value, just a snippet from the url. The actual data follows that.

Comment: Can you link to the docs?

Comment: Not in full, no. It is a private link on this particular AWS AMI, that is only available when the machine is running.

Comment: Decoding the percent encoding your "record" starts with `{"`. Are you perhaps meant to pass in JSON string?

Comment: What does you data dict look like? It is supposed to be `{"record":{field:value...}}`

Comment: No special characters in the names. its just string variable names with float values, e.g. : `{'x1':1.0, 'x2': 0.75....}`

Comment: But what exact format do you have it in?  Are you passing a dict with a record key and a sub dict of key/value fields?

Comment: I was not doing that, no. The **record=** was added solely by their Swagger docs. I will try adding that as a top level key, and then nesting my key/value fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'GET' requests don't have data, that's for 'POST' and friends.

You can send the query string arguments using `params` kwarg instead:

```
>>> params = {'record': '{"'}
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/explain', params=params)
>>> response.request.url
'http://www.example.com/explain?record=%7B%22'
```

Comment: So, if I were to use params, I'd have to pre-form the remainder of the string that would be produced by this? And I assure you, this is indeed a "GET" request that requires data, per the API I am using.

Comment: No.  You send a dict of `{query_key: query_value}` as shown.  Don't try to prepare the query string manually, unless you want to muck around with `urllib.quote` and basically be in a world of pain.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the API requires data, because that's not playing HTTP properly.  If it really does, you should not have much faith in that API - it will probably break horribly if any caching or proxying come into play.

Comment: When I simply pass the dict to params though, it doesn't include the "record=" piece that is otherwise missing.

Comment: Wim, I have added a link to a screenshot from the documentation.

Comment: Nowhere in your screenshot does it say to send data.  It says to send `model_name` by path (i.e. part of url before the `?`) and `record` by query (i.e. part of the url after the `?`)

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood how to modify that. That's the fix. Thanks, wim.

Comment: To add clarity, wim was correct about it needing to be in params, so the final solution ended up being: `params = {"record": json.dumps(data)}`

Answer (score -1):

From the comments i felt the need to explain this.

`http://example.com/sth?key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue`

Let's assume  you have a url like the above in order to call with python requests you only have to write

```
 response = requests.get('http://example.com/sth', params={
                          'key':'value', 
                           'anotherkey':'anothervalue'
                         })
```

Have in mind that if your value or your keys have any special character in them they will be escaped thats the reason for the `%7B%2` part of url in your question.